# Mozilla Add-on allow Ace Editor code validation

Tags: firefox-addon, ace-editor

Ace Editor uses this thing called 'blob' to create the Worker (which finds errors in code) and I want to use it in my Firefox extension. The console log showed errors like:

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at blob:moz-extension://{extension-private-uuid}

I am able to fix this using

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' blob:; object-src 'self'",
```

but I read that Add-ons that use the `blob:` keyword will get rejected from AMO because of major security risks. Is that likely still the case considering that it's a library? If so, then is there any other way of getting the worker to work without blob and *without editing any files?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.

There is an Ace Editor setting

```
ace.config.set('loadWorkerFromBlob', false);
```

which disables the loading of the worker file via blob. Yayyy!